# (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on "0.0.0.0" (tiemd out) ) error

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds

I've made an API server with Flask and hosted and distributed with AWS, but the server is not connected to the DB. I am assuming that the host address is probably wrong. I tried localhost, VPS IP address, public IP address assigned by AWS, etc, but it could not connect.

I also created RDS on AWS.

Which IP address should I use? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is an error message

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.31.0.0' (timed out)")

[20/Nov/2020 11:15:13] "POST /query/KAKAO HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `172.31.0.0` is the wrong IP. You should use db instance endpoint url.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Are you talking about a URL written in this way?  'database-chatbot.csdgsdgttav4v.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com'

Comment: Yes, that is the correct DB url.

Comment: Also, make sure that your API server's IP should be whitelisted on the RDS security group. 
Try to avoid posting the FULL DB ENDPOINTS on the public forum.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the right **database url** following this pattern

```
dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
```

refer to this topic https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#mysql

and since you are using `mysql` database on `AWS`, it should be like so :

```
mysql+mysqldb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:3306/DB_NAME
```

`HOST` should be **db instance endpoint url** as per this screen

[image]

refer to this doc https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-mysql-db/ section Step 3: Connect to the MySQL Database